# "Strange Scrap Metal" after killing a metal dragon. What do you do next?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I have installed the [Immersive Creatures Mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/24913/?).
After fighting a metal dragon I looted it and found "Strange Scrap Metal" which had "Blackreach" written on it.

I read in the discussion on that mod that this is a "quest" of some form in the mod, but they did not give any details.
I traveled back to blackreach and walked around a bit, but nothing happened.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what all this stuff is for (thanks to @Ids for the answer to get me started) :
It is to create metal dragons.

In the [Debate hall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Debate_Hall) in Blackreach, you will find a book in the side room at the top of the stairs.  That book is a "Construction Schematic" for metal dragons.

The book will tell you to go to [Tower of Mzark](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tower_of_Mzark) to find Mzark for the pieces that you will need.  Once you are in the tower you will find Mzark (a spectral being).  Kill him and loot the items you need.

As a side note: He also has a spell tome for summoning a "Dwarven Sphere" (expert level spell)

Answer (score 3):

From:

http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/796633-skyrim-immersive-creatures/?p=8839372

Seems you need to look for the auditorium in [Blackreach](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blackreach). Looking at the [map](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/File:SR-map-Blackreach.jpg) I cannot find something that looks like an auditorium. Perhaps it is the debate hall.

From:

http://www.ilbe.com/1727226282

Seems you also need a cube and a book. (And cannot translate the rest, I do not speak Korean). The same book/cube requirement was mentioned somewhere else as well.

This is all I could find. If you discover how it works. Please answer your own question, or leave comments so others can find the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out before i play next and post back if I figure anything out.